# CSS 100% height of container with min-height

Tags: html, css

I have a situation where I am trying to make an element occupy 100% of the height of its container - and the container element only has min-height specified. Unfortunately, when I do this, the height directive is ignored. [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/57EZn/3/). The "b" div, the red one, should fill the entire parent. It doesn't, not in IE7, Chrome, or FF3.6.

If I had "height: 1px" to the container, the "a" div, then "b" is stretched to the entire height of "a". [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/57EZn/4/). But this only in FF3.6 and IE7, not in Chrome. So I guess I am doing something wrong here.

I feel like this is a common problem that there must be a solution to that I'm just not seeing. What is the best way to achieve stretch-to-height in this case?

Comment: The parent container must have a specified height. Not just a min-height.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your CSS means that the child element's height is 100% of the specified height of the parent element. If you do not specify a height for the parent, then the 100% doesn't mean anything. Hence it doesn't work.

What you want can be achieved by using `position:relative` on the parent and `position:absolute` on the child:

http://jsfiddle.net/57EZn/25/

It's not a beautiful solution but it does what you are after.

Comment: Ah, yes, as I remember it this hack is sometimes used to fix other layout issues. I tried playing around with the position rule, but couldn't find the correct combination. Logically, I don't see why setting position should alter the height of the inner div, but it evidently works and I might be able to use this solution. Thanks.

Comment: It's not only the `position:absolute` that makes it alter the height. The height is altered by a specified `top` AND `bottom`. This forces the child element to "attach" itself to the top and bottom positions that you specify RELATIVE to it's parent. `bottom:0` in this case means "the lowest possible within parent". In other words: "size to match your parent's height".

Comment: Now I get it. In other words, it also works if I remove the "height: 100%" directive from the inner div, because top and bottom do the work.

Comment: Because the salient code is tucked away in jsfiddle this answer is incomplete.

Comment: this won't work to let the parent be stretched out by the child - if it's content is higher than the min-height of the parent. Which is probably the whole point of using min-height anyway.